# Can't login to phpMyAdmin with password - XAMPP on Windows 7

Tags: phpmyadmin, windows-7, xampp, passwords

I also have XAMPP installed on Linux Mint on a laptop and it works fine. At least the Linux version prompted me to set passwords.

On Windows, I used phpMyAdmin -> User Accounts, created a new user (admin/[password]), gave it global privileges, changed the config.inc.php to read...

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = ''; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

But when I try to login with that user/password, I can't. I'm positive it's not a typing error caps lock etc.

Error 1045: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I *can* login as 'root' with the config.inc file set to 'cookie' and 'AllowNoPassword' set to 'true' or just set 'auth_type' to 'config' and the phpmyadmin page opens up. So what am I missing please?

Comment: Fixed it. I had 'host name' set to 'any host [%]' and changed that to 'local.' Knocking em down in the city. The peeps here are awesome for not handing a newbie (me) the keys to the city so fast.